# Spring batch jobs are not getting triggered after spring boot upgrade to 2.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the below xml based batch configuration but the jobs are not getting executed. I do not see any error while bringing up the application, I suspect there is a misconfiguration which Im not able to figure out. The below is the configuration:

Application.java look like the below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {ValidationAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource("classpath:/application.xml")
@ComponentScan(value = "com.abc.xyz.app.configuration") //retrives dataSource
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
    }
}
```

application.xml

```
    <import resource="classpath:/app-batch-context.xml"/>   
    <import resource="classpath:/job_1.xml"/>   
    <import resource="classpath:/schdeuler_1.xml"/>
```

app-batch-context.xml has the below contents.

```
<bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry"/>

        <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
            <property name="jobRepository" ref="appJobRepository"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jobOperator" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
            <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer"/>
            <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
            <property name="jobRepository" ref="appJobRepository"/>
            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>
        </bean> 

       <bean id="appJobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
           <property name="lobHandler" ref="lobHandler"/>
           <property name="serializer" ref="xStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer"/>
           <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        </bean>

       <bean id="xStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer"/>        
       <bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler"/>

       <!-- Wrapper bean to hold the applicationcontext, and make it accessible to all the objects-->
       <bean id="appContext" class="com.app.core.AppContextInitializer"></bean>     
       <bean id="stepListner" class="com.app.core.step.APPStepExceutionListner"></bean>
       <bean id="jobListner" class="com.app.core.job.APPJobExecutionListner"></bean>  

       <!-- abstract base Job, all jobs will extend this Job -->
       <batch:job id="APPBaseJob" abstract="true" job-repository="appJobRepository">
             <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="jobListner"/>
             </batch:listeners>
       </batch:job>

       <!-- abstract base Job, all the steps will extend this step-->
       <batch:step id="abstractStep" abstract = "true">
             <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref ="stepListner"/>
             </batch:listeners>
       </batch:step>
```

job_1.xml

```
<batch:job id="myTestJob" parent="APPBaseJob">

        <batch:step id="myTestPreProcessorStep" next="myTestStopProcessingDecider">         
            <batch:tasklet ref="myTestPreProcessorTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:decision id="myTestStopProcessingDecider" decider="stopProcessingDecider">
            <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="myTestFileNameValidatorStep" />
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED"/>
        </batch:decision>
        .
        .
        .
<batch:step id="myTestCustomInputValidatorStep" next="myTestTransformStep">         
            <batch:tasklet ref="myTestCustomInputValidatorTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="myTestTransformStep" parent="abstractStep" next="myTestFileTransferStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="myTestFileItemReader" processor="myTestXmlProcessor" writer="myTestItemWriter" 
                    commit-interval="#{stepExecutionContext.get('APPBATCHCONTEXT').appBatch.toBeProcessedSize}"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

         <batch:step id="myTestFileTransferStep" next="myTestPostProcessorStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="myTestFileTransferTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>   

    </batch:job>

    <!-- File Reader -->
    <bean class="com.app.core.reader.v1.APPJaxbFileEntityReader" id="myFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="batchContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext.get('APPBATCHCONTEXT')}"></property>
        <property name="packageName" value="com.abc.jaxb.xyz.extract"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- File Content Writer-->
    <bean class="com.app.core.writer.v1.APPXmlJaxbItemWriter" id="myItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="batchContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext.get('APPBATCHCONTEXT')}"></property>    
        <property name="packageName" value="com.abc.jaxb.xyz.extract"></property>
    </bean>


  <bean id="myXmlProcessor" class="com.abc.app.xyz.customprocessor.XMLDocumentProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="batchContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext.get('APPBATCHCONTEXT')}"></property>
    <property name="somePropertyDataService" ref="somePropertyDataService"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myFileTransferTasklet" class="com.abc.xyz.customsender.mySenderTasklet">
    <property name="stepSkipDeciders" ref="skipStepDeciders"></property>
    <property name="router" ref="myRouter"></property>
  </bean>

  <bean class="com.abc.xyz.app.customsender.ABCRouter"
        id="myRouter"></bean>
```

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />
```

Scheduler has the below info : Using a custom jobLauncher but in turn uses a org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher to run the jobs.

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
    <bean id="myLauncher" class="com.abc.xyz.job.APPJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobCode" value="abc"></property>
    </bean>
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="abcScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="myLauncher" method="startJob" cron="${abcFreq}"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Job frequency will be in properties file with a cron expression * */5 * * * *

Please do let me know if any pointer is there that I should check.

Spring boot upgrade from 1.5.x to 2.2.x

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try simply with @EnableBatchProcessing in your Application.java

```
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude= {ValidationAutoConfiguration.class,         WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
  @ImportResource("classpath:/application.xml")
  @ComponentScan(value = "com.abc.xyz.app.configuration") //retrives  dataSource
  @EnableScheduling
  @EnableBatchProcessing
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have tried that, and I end up in a error like saying spring.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.commonTaskExecutor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope. I have added the Stepscope bean in my xml configuration to resolve it, but end up in IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner error.